# Refreshing issue in a Metro app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

This is a strange issue I'm stuck with. I have an Windows Phone app which I'm porting to Win 8. It is basically a calender app structured the following way.

First a MainPage.xaml which has a preview of all options available. When you click the Calendar option. It navigates to a different page called Calendar. The whole data of the app is managed by a class called CycleManager which is a sealed class. Data stored in the `ApplicationDataContainer` which is the equivalent of `IsolatedStorage`.

The first time an instance is created, it reads from the `ApplicationDataContainer`

```
public sealed class CycleManager
{
    private static readonly CycleManager instance = new CycleManager();

    public CycleManager()
    {
        localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        ReadFromIsolatedStorage();

    }

    public static CycleManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }

    }
}
```

The data is saved when you navigate back to the main page.

So now, my problem is this, When i debug. It works fine. The saved data is displayed on the calendar. 
In the constructor of the Calendar class, I call a function called CreateCalendar and in which the data and images are rendered.

But if I run it from the Simulator, what happens is the saved data is not displayed, but when you navigate back to the mainpage and once again come back to calendar page. It renders.

How can the simulator show one behaviour while debugging and another by jus running the deployed application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the data from `ApplicationDataContainer` **asynchronously** (using **async/await** keywords)? Every action that takes more than 20ms (which is about everything that isn't some simple code manipulation) should be done asynchronously in WinRT.

Loading the data can take a while and depending on how your data binding is set up, you'll usually see the data come on your screen after 1-2 seconds or nothing at all if you didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` events (the Common folder in the VS templates has a `BindableBase` object doing this for you). If this is implemented correctly, data will pop up, just give it some time.

When you're debugging with breakpoints, the data gets loaded fast enough so it shows up correctly. If you navigate back and forward in the simulator, the data also had time to load in memory.

You might also consider loading the data on application startup and using an [extended splash screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/21/creating-a-fast-and-fluid-app-launch-experience.aspx) while it gets loaded.

*Edit:*
A good link to get started with async in Windows 8: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-Metro-Asynchrony-made-easy.aspx. In your scenario this would be

```
public CycleManager()
{
    localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    Task.Run(() => ReadFromIsolatedStorage());

}

public async Task ReadFromIsolatedStorage() { 
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings; 
    ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = 
            (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["Setting"]; 
}
```

Combine that with a correct implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged (e.g. through a class derived from BindableBase and using the `SetProperty` method in the setter).

Comment: No I'm not using async/await keywords. public void      ReadFromIsolatedStorage()
        {
            ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["Setting"]; }

Comment: how do i make a function aync?

Comment: I'm not in Windows 8 right now, but I added some example code that *should* work.

Comment: My gut tells me the biggest issue here is a timing issue. Everything that Bart said about the data being available before the binding occurs is spot on. If the data is loaded AFTER the bindings occur and your model does not provide change notifications, the bindings won't know and the data won't be shown. Using BindableBase, ObservableObject (from MVVM Lite) or manually implementing INotifyPropertyChanged will help. Don't forget that collections must also be observable. Use ObservableCollection<T> for this.

Comment: @JaredBienz-MSFT yeas Jared looks that that was the issue. The data is loaded after the bindings occur. And a lot of data had to be read from isolated storage. I fixed it with a work around. Instantiated an object of CycleManager in the MainPage.xaml. The MainPage.xaml is a dummy page where currently no data is displayed. So then I guess, by the time we navigate to Calendar page, all data is read from the ApplicationDataContainer and the StorageFiles.